# Custom material drop down with reactive form

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

recently I'm trying to create a custom dropdown component using value accessor but I can't set a value to this dropdown.

This part of the dropdown component

```html
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

ts part

```js
    @Input() foods:any
    get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
      }

      // set accessor including call the onchange callback
      set value(v: any) {
        console.log(v, "v");
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
          this.innerValue = v;
          this.onChangeCallback(v);
        }
      }
```

App Component
HTML:

```html
    <app-input-dropdown [foods]="foods" formControlName="dropdown">
          </app-input-dropdown>
```

ts :

```js
     this.foods = [
          { value: "steak-0", viewValue: "Steak" },
          { value: "pizza-1", viewValue: "Pizza" },
          { value: "tacos-2", viewValue: "Tacos" }
        ];

     ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    dropdown:[null]
    })
    const valueToSet = { value: "steak-0", viewValue: "Steak" }
        this.myForm.dropdown.patchValue({
    dropdown:valueToSet
    }) ;
      }
```

So this is not working, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of few changes/additions to your code. First, you should change the way of how you set value to the form:

```
const valueToSet = { value: "steak-0", viewValue: "Steak" }
        this.myForm.dropdown.patchValue({
    dropdown:valueToSet
    }) ;
```

Executing this will produce an error because there should be no 'dropdown' keyword inside `this.myForm.dropdown.patchValue`. It should be - `this.myForm.patchValue`. But even after correcting this, the right way to set a value is:

```
this.myForm.controls["dropdown"].setValue("pizza-1");
```

or when using patchValue:

```
this.myForm.patchValue({dropdown: 'pizza-1'});
```

that is, to change the value of the select list programmatically, you should base on the `id` and not on the object itself.

Next is to make sure that you have `writeValue()` method in your custom control:

```
 writeValue(val: string): void {
    this.selectedOption = val;
  }
```

Then finally, bind the `selectedOption` (or `innerValue` in your case) to the `mat-select` tag:

```
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

No need to change anything in your app component html. It will still be using Reactive forms:

```
<app-input-dropdown [foods]="foods" formControlName="dropdown">
          </app-input-dropdown>
```

I can provide a sample in Stackblitz if you will still encounter a problem. Just let me know.